# Как переключиться на старую версию обработки исключений?

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, у меня старый проект, в котором используется старая форма обработки исключений. Как мне ее использовать?
Я попробовал написать обработку исключений через `try/catch`, но мне пишет ошибку компиляции:

```
    >..\src\main.cpp(1263) : error C2713: В каждой функции допускается применение только одной формы обработки исключений
1>..\src\main.cpp(1324) : error C2872: string: неоднозначный символ
```

Если надо, могу прикрепить файл для примера кода.
Что можете подсказать? Можно ли отключить старую версию обработки исключений и использовать новую или наоборот?

Например:

```
if(nosound)
{
    ALERR;
    if(context) alcDestroyContext(context);
    if(device) alcCloseDevice(device);
    conoutf("sound initialization failed!");
}
```

После:

```
if(nosound)
{
    ALERR;
    if(context) alcDestroyContext(context);
    if(device) alcCloseDevice(device);
    ErrExcept = "sound initialization failed!"; // change
    throw ErrExcept;        // change
}
```

Comment: Что значит "старая" и "новая" формы? Приведите код до и после.

Comment: И да, файл целиком прикреплять не надо. напишите прямо в тексте вопроса упрощенную часть кода, по которой будет ясно о чем идет речь

Answer (score 4):

[Описание ошибки C2713](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s190313z.aspx) гласит:

> Нельзя использовать [структурированную обработку исключений](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) (`__try`/`__except`) и обработку исключений C++ (`try`/`catch`) в одной и той же функции.

Так как в коде у Вас явно не видно ни того, ни другого, предложу, что либо Вы привели не ту часть кода, на которую указывает ошибка, либо, например, `ALERR` является макросом, который разворачивается во что-то подходящее. Хотя, наличие `throw` тоже говорит об использовании обработки исключений C++.

В любом случае, решение должно быть очевидно и следует из описания ошибки.

Comment: возможно, там был `__try`/`__except`, а ТС добавил `throw`.